# AJAX not working in Rails same-page update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to build a Q&A app with Ajax on the Index.html.erb. I manage to get the form remotely loading, but when saving the records, the AJAX does not work and the user is taken to the normal show.html.erb. Apart from the Ajax not kicking off, everything works well.

My code is as below:

**index.html.erb** (Contain a partial for input, and a partial for results)

```
<div>
  <h3 class="section_title">  Q&A </h3>
  <hr>
  <div id="qanda-form" style="display:none;"> </div>
</div>
<div id="qandas">
  <%= render 'qandas/qanda' %>
</div>
```

**_qanda.html.erb** (is the partial for results)

```
<% @qandas.each do |my_qanda| %>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div>
      Created  <%= local_time(my_qanda.created_at) %>, by  <%= User.find_by(id: my_qanda.user_id).full_name %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**_form.html.erb** (is the input form - has nested form via Cocoon)

```
<%= simple_form_for @qanda, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>
  <div class="col-md-12 form-inputs">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <%= f.input :title, label: 'Q&A Title:' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="qandasquestions">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :qandasquestions do |builder| %>
      <% render 'qandas/qandasquestion_fields', f: builder %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="links btn-group" style="min-height: 34px !important">
      <%= f.button :submit, "Publish Q&A", class: "btn btn-default" %>
      <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Question', f, :qandasquestions, class: 'btn btn-default', data: {association_insertion_node: '.qandasquestions', association_insertion_method: :append} %>
      <%= link_to 'Back', qandas_path, class: "btn btn-default" %>
      <%= f.input :company, :as => :hidden, :input_html => {:value => current_user.company} %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Controller**:

```
def index
  @qandas = Qanda.all
  respond_to do |format|
    @qandas = Qanda.all
    format.html
    format.json
  end
end

def create
  @qanda = current_user.qandas.build(qanda_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @qanda.save!
      @qandas = Qanda.all
      format.html { redirect_to @qanda, notice: 'Qanda was successfully created.' }
      format.json {render :layout => false}
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @qanda.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

**create.js.erb**

```
$('#qandas').html("<%= j render partial: 'qandas/qanda' %>");
$('#qanda-form').slideUp(350);
```

**new.js.erb**

```
$('#qanda-form').html("<%= j render 'qandas/form' %>");
$('#qanda-form').slideDown(350);
```

Anybody can see why the Ajax does not kick off please? why am I redirected to the traditional SHOW page please?

Comment: the request you're sending is of `js` not `json` so remove `format.html` and `format.json` and just write `format.js` and your instance variable will be available in `create.js.erb` as well.

Comment: Hey Gagan, thanks a lot. I made the change and get the following error :

`ActionController::UnknownFormat
Extracted source (around line #38):
            end
    end
      respond_to do |format|
      @qandas = Qanda.all

        format.js`

Comment: I m sure this must not be difficult, certainly I am missing a small point.

Comment: @GaganGupta, what do you mean by "your instance variable will be available in create.js.erb as well."?

Comment: `@qanda` and `@qandas` are instance variables and they'll be available on views as well. Here the view would be `create.js.erb`. umm, I am posting an answer as I cannot write the code here. just let me know if it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your code to this and let me know if it's working?

```
def create
  @qanda = current_user.qandas.build(qanda_params)
  if @qanda.save!
    @qandas = Qanda.all
  else
    @errors = @qanda.errors 
  end
end
```

Comment: It is working now, there were a few other things to change, you put me in the right direction again. thank you . Last one, do you know why best_in_place does not work on the view generated via AJAX ? It was working when Ajax was broken, now Ajax is fixed and best_in _place no longer works.

Comment: I am glad you got it working, what do you mean by `best_in_place` ?

Comment: If you've got time, try to dig deeper why your code wasn't working. format.js expects some arguments. example: 
`format.js { render 'create', locals: { qanda: @qanda, qandas: @qandas } }`

but do it later when you get it working perfectly, not now :D

Comment: Sure. It was the good opportunity as well to understand the whole render/remote process.

Comment: what's  best_in_place?

Comment: This one : https://rubygems.org/gems/best_in_place/versions/3.1.0. It allows users to edit a page directly on the `show.html.erb`, without going through the `edit.html.erb`

Comment: All right, Actually you add the invocation in create.js.erb also. `jQuery(".best_in_place").best_in_place();` 

It happens because dom doesn't have the info regarding the new item which is created. you'll have to tell it explicitly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183438/discussion-between-etienne-and-gagan-gupta).